# jQuery .width() sometimes works; sometimes doesnt?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Simple code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($('.slide-background').width());
});
```

and simple html:

```
<div class="testdiv">
      <img class="slide-background" src="img/slide.png"/>
</div>
```

As well as simple CSS:

```
        body {
            margin: 0; padding: 0;
            height: 100%; width: 100%;
        }

        html {
            margin: 0; padding: 0;
            height: 100%; width: 100%;
        }   
        .testdiv {

            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%; 
            height: 100%; 
            background-color: black;
        }
```

Why on earth does it output the width whenever it wants? Sometimes the width actually gets logged, however most of the time a 0 is returned.

Comment: Could be to do with document ready. document ready triggers when the DOM is ready and loaded **but** before images are fully loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In jQuery `$(document).ready()` runs code when the DOM is loaded (which does not include images), `$(window).load()` runs code when everything is loaded.

Simply put, the image width is 0 because it hasn't loaded at the point your code is running.

Use `$(window).load()` instead.

Comment: @MitchS: On StackOverflow is also a time limit of 10mins before you can do so :) So wait 10mins or a day, then ask or not, eitherway knowing your answer will not only help OP but also possibly many future users with similar problems should provide that warm fuzzy feeling you are after :) oh an +1 on the answer off course.

Comment: Sometimes wait for 100 images to get the width of one is not an option.

Comment: @roXon in this case I only need to wait for one image. Thank you for your input too, however.

Answer (score 5):

DOM is ready but your image is still being rendered by the browser.

```
var $image = $('.testdiv img');

var img = new Image();          // in memory image
img.src = $image[0].src;        // set SRC
img.onload = function(){        // as soon it's loaded
   alert( img.width ) ;         // WORKS!
}
```

Comment: +1 I like the idea of being able to target a specific image element. that is very interesting.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl thanks! In my experience building galleries, plugins, I cannot rely on the page weight (in images MB) to retrieve a desired value. Hope it makes sense

Comment: It makes perfect sense. I never had a scenario in which I had to worry about it so only after reading your comment on the other answer and seeing this answer I was very intrigued and it sounds like a very very handy solution to be aware off. I shall shamelessly copy your code into my little bag of tricks :)

Answer (score 3):

Because the width is not known until the image has loaded.

As the W3C recommends, you should set `width` and `height` attributes for `<img>` so that the correct width and height are shown (and known) before the image has finished loading.  If you have a very large image, your layout can be completely screwed up by it not taking up any space before it has loaded.